# Invalid handle error in TerminateThread

Tags: c++, winapi, signals

I have an application, which has registered handle routine via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` . Thing is on break signal I have to do some cleanup before exiting, and that is when problems begin. Because, other threads keeps on running and using some of the resources which should freed I got access violation during cleanup. I tried to save thread instances which are using these resources and stop them before calling cleanup routine, but this did not help. I constantly get `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. I tried to get thread instance via `DuplicateHandle` also I tried to save only thread id and then get thread handle via `OpenThread` function. But still invalid handle error is displayed.

Also, when I enumerate all thread instance and trying to terminate them I get the same error. It seems to me like there are some "magic" around handle routine, which does not allow to terminate other threads from it.

Listing for enumerating all threads

```
HANDLE h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
                    if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                        THREADENTRY32 te;
                        te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
                        if (Thread32First(h, &te)) {
                            do {
                                if (te.dwSize >= FIELD_OFFSET(THREADENTRY32, th32OwnerProcessID) +
                                    sizeof(te.th32OwnerProcessID)) {
 HANDLE thread = OpenThread(THREAD_TERMINATE, FALSE, te.th32ThreadID);
                                        if (TerminateThread(thread , NUM_SIG_ACTION_1) == 0)
                                        {
  //                                          printf("terminate failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
                                            if( SuspendThread(thread ) == -1)
                                            {
//                                                printf("suspend failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                                te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
                            } while (Thread32Next(h, &te));
                        }
                        CloseHandle(h);
                    }
```

Listing for get thread via `DuplicateHandle`

```
//code in working thread
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(), GetCurrentProcess(), &g_hWorkerThread ,
                             DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
//code in handler routine

                if (TerminateThread( g_hWorkerThread , NUM_SIG_ACTION_1 ) == 0)
                {
                    printf("Terminate thread failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
                }
```

Listing for OpenThread

```
//code from worker thread
g_iWorkerThreadId = GetThreadId(GetCurrentThread());
//code in routine handler
HANDLE handle = OpenThread(THREAD_TERMINATE, FALSE, g_iWorkerThreadId); 
                   if (TerminateThread( handle , NUM_SIG_ACTION_1 ) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("Terminate thread failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
                    }
```

Is there anyway to force handle routine run in to current worker thread?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks on advance.

Comment: Without seeing any code I will have to conclude, that *You're Doing It Wrong*. If you want help, invest some time in writing a good question. The question should be self contained. Include code when you reference code in your question. Describe the actual problem you're facing, and the ultimate goal you're after.

Comment: I posted some parts from my code, but it is really strange that o matter which method I am using always I get the same error.

Comment: At `TerminateThread(h, NUM_SIG_ACTION_1)`, `h` is not a thread handle.

Comment: thanks, I fixed it but still the issue has not gone

Comment: Both `DuplicateHandle` and `OpenHandle` have return values that you are consistently ignoring. Evaluate them, to see whether the returned data is valid. Adding a `@err,hr` watch in the Visual Studio debugger is a convenient way to evaluate the return value of `GetLastError` while stepping through code.

Comment: Side note - [*"`TerminateThread` is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases ..."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do something yourself that the OS already does. Don't fight the system.
Let me suggest another way of working, that could simplify your code considerably.

When your main application thread gets the Ctrl signal, it wants to shut down the application.
You can have Windows do that for you, but you might leave resources in an undefined state, so that's why you want to shut down gracefully.

Likely, each thread already runs an event loop - that's the basic Windows applications paradigm. Upon the ctrl-signal, post events to your other threads and catch them in each thread's event loop. Add custom event code that will make them gracefully end themselves. You now only have to wait for all the thread handles to ensure all threads have ended.

Using TerminateThread is not a good idea, it is exactly the opposite of the graceful end of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

How one can sure calling `TerminateThread` will free the resource that is in use?

Only killing a process guarantees freeing of **kernel resources** used by the process.

In my humble experiences, I didn't found any multi-thread program runs good and stably without the clear and explicit exit mechanism.

Each thread must have an exit condition, when exiting it must free the resources, and the main thread (or controlling thread) must trigger the exit conditions and wait until all the other thread are exit.